# Shiny Consecutive reactive data tables

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I'm newbie in shiny and in r. I'm creating a dynamic shiny dashboard. where users  need to select a row  from fist table and with few columns cell values  users have to filter on anther data and it go on. 
From the new second table created by the user, Again a row is selected, in second table. And selected row some values is used to filter existing data set and display it in shiny. and so on.

I had written a sample code but its not working.

```
df <- data.frame(id = sample(c(1,2,3,4),15, replace = T ),
             day = sample(c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed"),15, replace = T),
             hour_hand = c(0:14),
             price =sample(c(121,221,112,231,444), replace = T))

df_day <- df %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
summarise(price = sum(price))


df_day_hour <- df %>% 
group_by(id, day) %>% 
summarise(price = sum(price))




ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "red",
                dashboardHeader(title = "2_level_drill_down"),
                dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(menuItem("Price", tabName = "tab_01", icon =icon("bar-chart")))),
                dashboardBody(tabItems(
                  tabItem(tabName = "tab_01",
                          tabsetPanel(
                            tabPanel("Id", DT::dataTableOutput("table_id")),
                            tabPanel("ID Day", DT::dataTableOutput("table_id_day")),
                            tabPanel("ID Day Hour",DT::dataTableOutput ("table_id_day_hour"))))
                  )))

server <- function(input, output){
#Id table
output$table_id <- renderDT(DT::datatable({
data =df
 }))

 #Id Day group_by  table
output$table_id_day <- renderDT(DT::datatable({
s = input$table_id_rows_selected
v <- unique(df[s,c("id")])
data = df_day[df_day$id %in% v,]
}))


 #ID Day Hour group_by  Table
 output$table_id_day_hour <- renderDT({
 s_3 = input$table_nodal_day_rows_selected
 id_3 <- unique(id_day_df[s_2,c("id")])
 day_2 <- unique(id_day_df[s_2,c("day")])
 data = df_day_hour[df_day_hour$id %in% id_3 & df_day_hour$day %in% day_2,]
 }) 




}


#####
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: How is it not working? Can you describe what happens and include any errors you're getting?

Comment: Error:'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix)

Comment: That error means that at some point, your data.frame is being subset to only a single variable (which gets simplified to a 1D vector, hence the error). I can't see any obvious place where that's happening, but that's the most likely cause of the error. I'd put `print(colnames(data))` in your `renderDT` statements to check where it's happening (make sure to `return(data)` afterwards

Comment: Actually, when I run your code, I can't reproduce your error. You also never define `id_day_df` which throws another error. Without a reproducible example, that's the best I can do

Comment: Actually, my issue is second drill down is showing wrong data. I think when i had created 2nd dynamic table after clicking a row of first table. This table is dynamic (subset of original 2nd table). But after clicking a row of 2nd table(subset of original 2nd table) for 3rd drill down is capturing row and indices of original 2nd table. I'm thinking to create  observe event tab for 2nd dynamic table(subset table )  to capture the real value of selected row of actual table whose value I need to filter on another table.